# How to sum specific data grid view cell with criteria?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I created a `DataGridView` where I am retrieving data by search customer id. I want to sum values in `TextBox` when I select some specific `CheckBox-es` of `DataGridView`.

But the problem is that it is adding all values in all cells of all rows but it should be like that for example; if `Column` number is 2, then pending value should be shown once in `TextBox` not after sum both duplicated `received` cell, and if Column numbers are different like `Column` number 1 and `Column` number 2 and both are selected, sum value should be there in `TextBox` which is named received from data grid view `received` cell.

I am attaching image and code also what I am trying to do. can someone guide how to do this?

[image: Screenshot]

```
Private Sub Getvalue()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then

            Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells(0).Value)

            If isSelected Then

                Dim pending As String = 0
                Dim received As String = 0
                Dim final amount As String = 0

                For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                    pending += Convert.ToDouble (DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(15).Value)
                    received += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(14).Value)
                    finalamount += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(12).Value)

                Next

                Label19.Reset Text()
                Label19.Text = pending
                Label20.Reset Text()
                Label20.Text = received
                Label24.Reset Text()
                Label24.Text = final amount

                If Label19.Text <= 0 Then
                    Label18.Text = ""
                Else
                    Label18.Text = Val(Label 24.Text - Label 19.Text)

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn on Option Strict as per my comment.

If there are not rows, your `For Each row` won't run so there is no need to check the `RowCount`.

Don't declare your accumulation variables inside the loop. They will be a new variable on each iteration. Your inner loop loops through all rows so, of course, you get the sum of all. Eliminate the inner loop.

I have no idea what `Reset Text()` is. A method can't have a space in its name. Anyway, it you are adding a new value it isn't necessary to clear the old one. If you do need to clear then set to `""`. Don't update your labels until after the loop. It is useless to update the user interface on each iteration. It will go by too fast for the user to see and it slows down the code.

In general, you need to do arithmetic or numeric comparisons with numeric types and set `.Text` properties with `String` type. The `Val` method has bee replace with several .net methods. `.Parse`, `.TryParse`, `Convert.` and in vb the `CInt`, `CDec`, etc.

```
Private Sub Getvalue()
    Dim pending As Double = 0
    Dim received As Double = 0
    Dim finalAmount As Double = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim isSelected As Boolean = CBool(row.Cells(0).Value)
        If isSelected Then
            pending += CDbl(row.Cells(15).Value)
            received += CDbl(row.Cells(14).Value)
            finalAmount += CDbl(row.Cells(12).Value)
        End If
    Next
    Label19.Text = pending.ToString
    Label20.Text = received.ToString
    Label24.Text = finalAmount.ToString
    If pending <= 0 Then
        Label18.Text = ""
    Else
        Label18.Text = (finalAmount - pending).ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Normally you would have a purchase. The purchase would have a table in the database with fields like purchase number, date, customer, etc. You would have another table with purchase details. The details table would have fields like details number (primary key), a foreign key purchase number which must match an entry in the purchase table, an item ID and a price.
When a customer wants to return an item or items from a purchase. You would enter the purchase number and fill your grid from the purchase details table.

```
Select * From PurchaseDetails Where purchaseNumber = @purchaseNumber
```

Put the check mark by each item returned and sum up the price column.

> Purchase Table
>
> PurchaseID | CustomerID | Date
>
> Purchase Details Table
>
> DetailID | PurchaseID | ItemCode | ItemPrice

Comment: your code is working fine but one thing left that i said in my question that my basic criteria is cm and you will notice that it has two entries of cm no 2 in which cm no 2 has two items billed but payment received once and that value is 62358 and when i check both cm no 2 entries it sum both 62358 but i want only single 62358 should be sum otherwise your code is working great. if you can guide then kindly guide. please check my image attached at the time of question posted.

Comment: Are all the rows checked in column(0) one CMNO? All CMNO 2 or CMNO 1?

Comment: i think you have not understand my question. i explain you again suppose jerry has purchased one apple of 1$ and one orange of 1$ and paid 2$ and cm no is 1 now he want to return both cm no 1 items returning amount should be 2 $ but in my case it is showing 4 $ because in DataGridView Row both items showing 2$ paid amount in payment section.similarly if there are multiple cm like 1,2,3 it should return original amount paid not adding duplicates. so i am asking for cm criteria.